# Swift - Retrieving information stored in custom tableview-cells

Tags: uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer, custom-cell, didselectrowatindexpath

I've implemented the longPressGesture in my custom cells, and now I need to retrieve the information that is stored in these cells.

My cellForRowAtIndexPath-function looks like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "cellLongPressed:")
    longPress.delegate = self
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1

    let cellID = "cell"
    var mcell:CusCell = self.tv.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as CusCell

    mcell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

    let data = mainList[indexPath.row] as SecondModel

    var dateStr:String = String()
        dateStr = printDate(data.date)

        mcell.mainLabel.text = data.receiver
        mcell.recLabel.text = "Message sent at \(dateStr)"
        mcell.imageLabel.image = UIImage(named: icons[0])
        mcell.messType = messageType
```

return mcell
    }

My didSelectRowAtIndexPath-function looks like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedCell: CusCell = tv.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CusCell

    messagType = selectedCell.messType

    println(messagType)

}
```

My cellLongPressed-function looks like this:

```
func cellLongPressed(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        println("STATE ENDED")
        //Do Whatever You want on End of Gesture
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){
        println("STATE BEGAN")
        //Do Whatever You want on Began of Gesture
    }
}
```

Now as you probably can guess, the integer stored in "selectedCell.messType" never gets printed. I don't really understand why this shouldn't work, is my declaration of the "selectedCell" wrong?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't show where `messType` gets set, and you aren't doing anything with the long press recogniser. Can you add more information to the question, like perhaps the rest of the cellForRow method?

Comment: As a general suggestion, don't "store" data in cells. Cells display the data from your model, they shouldn't be used to store things.

Comment: @jrturton My functions have now been added, I hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why can't you read the data back from the model if messageType is part of the model? Reading the data back from the cell is not a good way to do it.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  {

    let data = mainList[indexPath.row] as SecondModel
    var messagType = data.messageType
    println(messagType)

}
```

If its you want to log the values inside long press event

```
func cellLongPressed(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        var point = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
        {
            let data = mainList[indexPath.row] as SecondModel
            var messagType = data.messageType
            println(messagType)
        }
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried with this too, but still nothing gets printed.

Comment: are you trying with long press? or tap? @frank21

Comment: Shouldn't the messagType get printed even if it's not implemented in the cellLongPressed function?

Comment: No. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will not be called if its a long press. It will only be called if we tap(shorter than our long press duration)

Comment: Okay, my bad, I tried it now and it worked perfectly :) But I have another and more basic question: I have declared my cellLongPressed function in my "outer closure", and now I need to get the messagType variable to this function, how can this be done. I tried declaring another variable in my outer closure and setting the messagType to this, but it didn't work.

Comment: did u try declaring it as a class property and accessing as self.messageType ?

Comment: I declared the messagType like this: var messagType:Double = Double(), and in my cellLongPressed-function like this: if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {println("\(self.messagType)"). Sorry for the mess.

Comment: ok and that's not working? so messageType is not linked to the model? Its a constant?

Comment: It just prints 0 every time. Just to be clear, my logic is like this: 1) I declare my variable in my outer closure 2) The variable gets changed in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath-function 3) The changed variable is used in my cellLongPressed-function declared in my outer closure. Does this seem correct?

Comment: can you put your code in a github gist and show me?

Comment: Didn't see what you added to your answer until now, but it works :) Thank you very much, especially the part about creating your own cell-pointer will be much appreciated!